# Nested structures not sorted correctly

Tags: struct, coldfusion, cfml, lucee, cfloop

I am looping over a query, building an array of structures

```
<cffunction name="QueryConvert" returntype="any" output="false">
    <cfargument name="q" type="query" required="yes">
    <cfargument name="page" type="numeric" required="no" default="1">
    <cfargument name="rows" type="numeric" required="no" default="500">
    <cfset var result = structnew()>
    <cfset var rowStruct = structnew()>
    <cfset var col = "">
    <cfset result["page"] = arguments.page>
    <cfset result["total"] = ceiling(arguments.q.TotalrecordCount/arguments.rows)>
    <cfset result["records"] = arguments.q.TotalrecordCount>
    <cfset result["rows"] = arraynew(1)>
    <cfset queryDeleteColumn(arguments.q,'TotalrecordCount')>
    <cfset queryDeleteColumn(arguments.q,'rowNum')>
    <cfset columnLabels = QueryColumnArray(arguments.q)>
    <cfset rowStruct = [:]><!--- Tada an ordered struct --->
    <cfloop array="#columnLabels#" item="col">
         <cfset rowStruct[col] = q["#col#"]>
    </cfloop>
    <cfdump var="#result#" abort>
    <cfreturn result />
</cffunction>
```

but when I view the nested structures, the order of the keys is all mixed up. I expected them to match the order of the column names in the database table.

Comment: Does `arguments.q.getMeta().getColumnLabels()` return the sorted list?

Comment: This page, however, says `getColumnlist`  is said/supposed to return the column names in their original order and not sorted alphabetically: http://burnignorance.com/coldfusion-application-development/how-to-get-database-table-columnlist-from-a-query-resultset-in-coldfusion/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is you need to use a ordered struct. The long version looks like this:

First we need to look at some sample data

```
 <cfscript>
 q = queryNew("id,name,category","Integer,Varchar,Varchar", 
     [{id=1, name="One", category="Cat"},{id=2, name="Two", category="Dog"}]
 );


 writedump(q);
 </cfscript>
```

Let's look at out sample data. Note that the columns are not as expected.

[image]

Now let's get our columnLabels ready to go. Note that we are creating an array.

```
 </cfscript>
 result.rows = [];

 columnLabels = q.getMeta().getColumnLabels();
 writedump(columnLabels);
 </cfscript>
```

[image]

```
<cfloop query="q">
   <cfset rowStruct = [:]><!--- Tada an ordered struct --->
   <cfloop array="#columnLabels#" item="col">
       <cfset rowStruct[col] = q["#col#"]>
   </cfloop>

   <cfset arrayappend(result.rows, rowStruct)>
</cfloop>

<cfdump var="#result.rows#">
```

**Tada**

[image]

**Furthermore**

This is all easier to read with `cfscript`

```
<cfscript>
for (row in q)  {
    rowStruct = [:];
    for (col in columnLabels)    {
        rowStruct[col] = q["#col#"];
    }
    result.rows.append(rowStruct);
}
</cfscript>
```

For a live version see: [CFFiddle.com](https://cffiddle.org/app/file?filepath=7e7ae597-00b3-47a7-968f-c75a1c9908cd/d6281559-1270-4b5a-b955-8fcfb923b62a/e5a5d860-0593-4a8c-b751-1425c4d805fb.cfm)

Comment: sing Lucee and here is what I have `<cfargument name="q" type="query" required="yes"> <cfset arguments.q = arguments.q.getMeta().getColumnLabels()>` - but there is an error saying no `The function [getMeta] does not exist in the Object, only the following functions are available: [addColumn,addRow,columnArray,columnCount,columnData,columnExists,columnList,currentRow,deleteColumn,deleteRow,....t].`

Comment: I am updating my code in my Post of the function I have

Comment: Updated my Question with Updated Code I am using now as a Function

Comment: Yes, using Lucee

Comment: fixed it, there were some missing loops in my function, the Lucee Function does work.

Comment: FWIW, the documented getMetaData( queryObj ) function should work in both.